# Conditional select value based on existence in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of users, and a table that keeps track of threads and the users that are involved in each thread.  I am trying to be able to craft a `SELECT` statement that I can look at any thread, and get back the full list of users along with a column of whether or not they are present in it.  Initially and naively I used the following to start:

```
SELECT 
listusers.idx as Value,
CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as Label,
False as selected
FROM
listUsers
WHERE 
listusers.customerId = 0
```

This just gets me back all of the users and at this point I programatically looked to the other table and manually switched on the users that are in it.

My attempt at doing this via a query is the following -

```
SELECT l.idx as Value,
CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as Label,
IF(h.userId IS NULL,False, True) as Selected
FROM listusers l
LEFT JOIN helpmessageparticipants h ON l.idx = h.userId
WHERE l.customerId = 0 AND 
h.parentThreadId={Root Container.threadId})
```

But for some reason that only returns the users that ARE selected.  If only 3 users are in the thread, I only get those three back and all are `True` in the selected.  What I want, end result, is to always get back all the users (the users where l.customerId=0) and and additional column of whether or not they are present in helpmessageparticipants for a certain thread as a true or false boolean column.  Whats wrong with my second query?

I am using MySQL 5.6.

Comment: the table which is `LEFT JOIN`ed in this case `helpmessageparticipants` can't have non `IS NULL` filter check conditions which `h.parentThreadId = value` is otherwise it will filter as a `INNER JOIN`.. Very common MySQL error it would be ok if the condition was `h.parentThreadId IS NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the

```
h.parentThreadId={Root Container.threadId})
```

condition out of the `WHERE` clause and into the join condition, otherwise it converts your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT l.idx as Value,
CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as Label,
IF(h.userId IS NULL,False, True) as Selected
FROM listusers l
LEFT JOIN helpmessageparticipants h ON l.idx = h.userId AND 
       h.parentThreadId={Root Container.threadId})
WHERE l.customerId = 0
```

This is discussed in the manual under ['Outer Join Optimization'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html):

> For a LEFT JOIN, if the WHERE condition is always false for the generated NULL row, the LEFT JOIN is changed to an inner join

In your example, `h.parentThreadId={Root Container.threadId})` will be false for a generated NULL row, thus the query changes to an `INNER JOIN` and you only get back the users that are selected.

Comment: *"This is discussed in the manual under 'Outer Join Optimization':"* Yes iám not sure it's this is MySQL specific only or if other databases system also do this as the `sql` tag is also tagged in this question.

Comment: @RaymondNijland This isn't specific to MySQL, it's how `LEFT JOIN` works in general. Note that adding `OR h.parentThreadId IS NULL` would also have resolved the problem. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3750c33897a288bd1860a0d03adec81c

Answer (score 0):

The `LEFT JOIN` version requires that the condition be in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause, as Nick points out.  I would write this as:

```
SELECT l.idx as Value,
       CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as Label,
       (h.userId IS NOT NULL) as Selected
FROM listusers l LEFT JOIN
     helpmessageparticipants h
     ON l.idx = h.userId AND 
        h.parentThreadId = {Root Container.threadId})
WHERE l.customerId = 0;
```

However, this assumes that there is only one match in `h` -- otherwise you will get duplicate rows.  For a single thread this might not be an issue.  But you might have other filtering conditions that allow multiple matches.For this reason, I think an `exists` clause might be more appropriate.

```
SELECT l.idx as Value,
       CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as Label,
       (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM helpmessageparticipants h
                WHERE l.idx = h.userId AND 
                      h.parentThreadId = {Root Container.threadId}
              )
       ) as Selected
FROM listusers l LEFT JOIN

WHERE l.customerId = 0;
```